# XMLT : replace values with values found in another xml

Tags: xslt

I have a file called ori.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <container>
        <elA>
            <el1>value1</el1>
            <el2>value2</el2>
        </elA>
         <elB>
            <el3>value3</el3>
            <el4>value4</el4>
            <el5>value5</el5>
         </elB>
          <elC>
            <el6>value5</el6>
         </elC>
     </container>
</root>
```

and another one called modifs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<els>
    <el2>newvalue2</el2>
    <el5>newvalue5</el5>
</els>
```

and I would like to obtain result.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <container>
        <elA>
            <el1>value1</el1>
            <el2>newvalue2</el2>
        </elA>
         <elB>
            <el3>value3</el3>
            <el4>value4</el4>
            <el5>newvalue5</el5>
         </elB>
          <elC>
            <el6>value5</el6>
         </elC>
     </container>
</root>
```

I'm a beginner in XSLT.
So I started to write a stylesheet with which I'm able to change value2 into newvalue2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="fileName" select="'modifs.xml'" />
  <xsl:param name="modifs" select="document($fileName)" />

  <xsl:param name="updateEl" >
  <xsl:value-of select="$modifs/els/el2" />
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//elA/el2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateEl" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But now I have to modify this stylesheet to be able to know which elements are in modifs.xml and find them in ori.xml. I don't know how to do that. Could you help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a key:

```
  <xsl:key name="ref-change" match="els/*" use="local-name()"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[key('ref-change', local-name(), $modifs)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref-change', local-name(), $modifs)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

However, using the third argument for the `key` function is only supported in XSLT 2 and later thus if you use an XSLT 1 processor you need to move the logic into the template, that requires using `for-each` to "switch" the context document

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$modifs">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="key('ref-change', local-name($this))">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref-change', local-name($this))"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:for-each select="$this">
             <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Put `name="identity"` on your identity transformation template.

Comment: Thanks. The XSLT 2 solution works perfectly and shows that I have a lot to learn. I tried unsuccessfully the XSLT 1 version. With Saxon 9.9, I get warnings "XTDE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /els", an error  "SXLM0001: Too many nested apply-templates calls. The stylesheet may be looping." and no output.

Comment: @user3172425, I have fixed the XSLT 1 suggestion, the previous suggestion did not switch back to the primary input document.

Comment: And it's now perfect. Thanks.